# How show basic validation messages in the text field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the validation messages below the text fields that require it as well as the example that is in the image that I found

**Example**

[image]

I have the following text fields on my form, with their respective validation done in **Javascript**

```js
//Function to validate ticket form
function validate_form() {
    valid = true;

    if (document.ticketForm.matricula.value == "") {
        alert("Verify the data again, enter the license plate");
        valid = false;
    }

    if (document.ticketForm.nombre.value == "") {
        alert("Verify the data again, enter the name of the applicant");
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form name="ticketForm" method="post" onchange="validate_form();">
                <div id="informacionTicket" class="user">
                    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketIdAppliInput">License:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="9" required id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketNameAppliInput">Full name:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Send</button>
</form>
```

What I don't want is to be shown those annoying `alert` at the top of the form

[image]

I want the message to be displayed as in the example image

**UPDATE:**

Try this possible solution but when entering a value the message is no longer deleted

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried the possible solution of @JarlikStepsto but it still doesn't work properly

[image]

```js
function validate(field) {
    const validateables = document.getElementsByClassName('validateable');
    const input = field;
    if (!input.value == "") {
        input.classList.add('invalid');      
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('invalid');
    }

    if (!input.value == "") {
        input.classList.add('invalid');      
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('invalid');
    }
}
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
}

.validation-message {
    display: none;
}

input.validateable.invalid + .validation-message {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="matricula" for="ticketIdAppliInput">Matrícula:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="9" required="required" id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user validateable"/>
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese la matricula</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="nombre" for="ticketNameAppliInput">Nombre completo:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese el nombre
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I will explain it better, I have two fields that matter to me that are compulsory "Matricula" and "Nombre Completo", when I am filling out the third field I do not get the validation message, this is the code I have, will I be doing something wrong?

```js
function validate(field) {
    const input = field;
    if (!input.value || input.value.length === 0) {
        input.classList.add('invalid');      
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('invalid');
    }
}
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
}

.validation-message {
    display: none;
}

input.validateable.invalid + .validation-message {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="matricula" for="ticketIdAppliInput">Matrícula:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="9" id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user validateable"/>
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese la matricula</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="nombre" for="ticketNameAppliInput">Nombre completo:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese el nombre
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="email" for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese el correo electronico
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: There are a million and one ways to accomplish this task. Dynamic or hard-coded fields, javascript or server-side processing... Please be more specific to how you want to accomplish this task. Also just because it can be important, use `===` when comparing values -> `if (document.ticketForm.matricula.value === "") {}`

Comment: add a span or other element u nder your textbox and add your messge to it, when validating

Comment: you can use Modal, hide it par default, and show it when you need user to correct the infos (switch the property of the Modal "display from none to block")

Comment: @JarlikStepsto Can you tell me the element that I should use under my text box

Comment: @daddygames I will take into account the comparison of values

Comment: Bootstrap got very good documentation, and one of the examples is validation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#validation

Comment: do you mean somethin like this? (leave license blank and type in somewhere something to start v alidation): https://jsfiddle.net/87tu6o0g/

Comment: @JarlikStepsto It's exactly what I want but check the update for what's happening

Comment: just updated the code: https://jsfiddle.net/87tu6o0g/1/

Comment: have a look at  my updated answer

Comment: does the updated version works for you?

Comment: I'm going to try the update and tell you how it works

Comment: @JarlikStepsto check again the question I just made an update with your possible solution but it doesn't work

Comment: what should be valid and what not? please write the rules, for showing the  text, then i  can help you modifiying the code

Comment: tried to fix your code (see new update in my answer) but without knowing, what is valid for you and what not i used empty field as invalid and not empty as valid

Comment: @JarlikStepsto It has to be valid when writing on it and not valid when not written

Comment: @JarlikStepsto All two fields both "Matricula" and "Nombre Completo" must be mandatory, but if you see it in the update when I say something about them, the validation message comes out, it shouldn't be like that, you can check if suddenly I have the code misspelled in my update

Comment: @JarlikStepsto check the detailed update I've done

Comment: @JarlikStepsto in update 2, only until I write and delete what I wrote in the field is that I get the validation messag, try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199868/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-jarlik-stepsto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a validation message under the field you need a element to display it.

It could be any div, span or whatever you want.

In my example i will use a span to demonstrate how it works:

```
<input onchange="validate();" type="text" class="validateable" validation-pattern="[0-9]*" />
    <div class="validation-message">Only numbers are allowed in this field!</div>
```

now in the js code we just have to validate for the pattern and set a input to invalid if it does not match the pattern:

```
function validate(){
  const validateables = document.getElementsByClassName('validateable');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(validateables, input => {
        const pattern = input.getAttribute('validation-pattern');
    if(!input.value.match('^' + pattern + '$')){
        input.classList.add('invalid');
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('invalid');
    }
  });
}
```

and the css to display validation text only if invalid:

```
.validation-message {
  display: none;
}

input.validateable.invalid + .validation-message{
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

**What this code does:**

The JS function looks for every input with the class "validateable" and iterates over them. Each element should have an attribute with an validation pattern `validation-pattern="[0-9]*"` Now the function checks, if the value of the input matches the pattern and add a class `invalid` to the input or removes it.
In the css i defined an invisible div `validation-message` but if the element bevor this div is an validateable input field, that is invalid, the div will be displayed and you can see the validation message.

Working fidle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h687eomf/

**UPDATE:**

in your case, you just want to validate the field, that you are changing, have a look at my changed example fidle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h687eomf/2/

**UPDATE 2:**

A try to fix your snippet, assuming that a field is valid when its value is not empty and invalid if the value is empty:

```js
function validate(field) {
    const input = field;
    if (!input.value ||  input.value.length === 0) {
        input.classList.add('invalid');      
    } else {
        input.classList.remove('invalid');
    }
}
```

```css
input {
    display: block;
}

.validation-message {
    display: none;
}

input.validateable.invalid + .validation-message {
    display: block;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="matricula" for="ticketIdAppliInput">Matrícula:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="9" required="required" id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user validateable"/>
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese la matricula</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="required-field" name="nombre" for="ticketNameAppliInput">Nombre completo:</label>
                                    <input onchange="validate(this)" maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user validateable" />
                                    <div class="validation-message">
                                        Verifique la información nuevamente, ingrese el nombre
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Check again the question I just placed an update on what happens to me when I start typing

Comment: just updated my fiddle to just validate the field, that ist changing at the moment